# How to Dynamically nest Row inside the column in html using foreach loop?

Tags: html, css, razor

I am trying to design something like in the below picture.
But I didn't get proper design, mostly showing  cannot be nested within .
I m using for each loop and trying to load data dynamic rows inside column.

My code as follows:

```
 <tr>
        <th>S no</th>
        <th>heading 1</th>
        <th>heading 2</th>
        <th>heading 3</th>
        <th>heading 4</th>
        <th>heading 5</th>       
 </tr> 
 @foreach (var items in Model.itemslist)  //conditions
            {
                if (items.id == 3)
                {
                    foreach (var itemsCheck in Model.itemslist)
                    {
                        if (itemsCheck.ICID == 4)
                        {
                            if (items.ICTID == itemsCheck.iParentID)
                            {                               
                                if (itemsCheck.FormID == items.FormID)
                                {
               
                <tr style="display: none">@{j = j + 1;}</tr>
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }                    
                    if (j > 0)
                    {                    
               
                <tr>
                    <td>@items.Sno</td>

                    <td>@items.Parts</td>  //(partA or PArtB or PArt C -2nd column rows)

                    @foreach (var item in Model.itemslist)
                    {
                        if (items.ICTID == item.iParentID)
                        {
                            if (item.ICID == 4)
                            {
                                if (item.iSrc != -1)
                                {
                        <tr>    ------------------------------------------HEre I cannot able to nest <tr> inside <td>;Showing error                         
                        <td >@item.data</td>          //data1,data2.....
                        <td >@item.value</td>           //a1,a2,b1....
                        <td >@item.doublevalue</td>    //aa,bbb,cc....
                        <td >@item.lastvalue</td>       //aa1,aa2.bb1.....
                           </tr>
                                 }
                              }
                          }
                      }
                </tr>
                    }
            }
            }
```

[image]

As asked, My model screenshot as follows:
[image]

Kindly help to me to get my result design as shown in image. Thanks in Advance

**PS:I tried rowspan, still not fixed**

Comment: Can you share the sample data of `Model.itemslist`?

Comment: @YiyiYou Hi I attached my screenshot of model..Plz checck

Comment: Can you share data with sample code,so that I can test your view code?

Comment: I didnt get you, as I have many records, Im confused what to share. My expectation along with expected design is as follows: Let say, I have a book with titles-Part A,Part B ...rows. THe subtitles  under the titles are comes under heading 2 i.e.,a1,a2,a3...and heading 3 ... heading 4 has the data with respect to 'title' column. heading 5 also got data with respect to 'subtitle' column. after condition satisfied, subtitles under titles are filter out and displayed here